# How to conditionally specify a variable in yocto .bb recipe

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I would like to do something like this:

```
if [ "${BB_NO_NETWORK}" == "1" ]; then
    SRCREV ?= "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee"
else
    SRCREV ?= "${AUTOREV}"
fi
```

But I get an unparsed error

Here is what I have got working.

```
SRCREV_FORMAT = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "v16_pcmx", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
SRCREV_d3v16 = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
SRCREV_v16 = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
SRCREV_pcmx-native = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
SRCREV_pcmx-pn-pcmx = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
SRCREV_pcmx = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
SRCREV_pn-pcmx = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
SRCREV = "${@bb.utils.contains('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', "", "${AUTOREV}", d)}"
```

This attempt fails:

```
SRCREV_FORMAT = "${@ "v16_pcmx" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_d3v16 = "${@ "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_v16 = "${@ "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pcmx-native = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pcmx-pn-pcmx = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pcmx = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pn-pcmx = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV = "${@ "" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK',TRUE)) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
```

This also fails

```
SRCREV_FORMAT = "${@ "v16_pcmx" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_d3v16 = "${@ "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_v16 = "${@ "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pcmx-native = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pcmx-pn-pcmx = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pcmx = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV_pn-pcmx = "${@ "d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
SRCREV = "${@ "" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
```

The error for this one looks like this:

```
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable SRCREV_v16, expression was ${@ "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') } which triggered exception TypeError: getVar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expand'
```

Lastly, this fails as well:

```
SRCREV_FORMAT = "${@'v16_pcmx' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
SRCREV_d3v16 = "${@'a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
SRCREV_v16 = "${@'a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
SRCREV_pcmx-native = "${@'d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
SRCREV_pcmx-pn-pcmx = "${@'d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
SRCREV_pcmx = "${@'d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
SRCREV_pn-pcmx = "${@'d09e0b91ae34d807d3df27908f045e58a52e0c4c' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
SRCREV = "${@'' if d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK') == '1' else '${AUTOREV}'}"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess on modern OE it's gonna look like this (untested):

```
SRCREV = "${@ "a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee" if bb.utils.to_boolean(d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK')) else d.getVar('AUTOREV') }"
```

using [inline python variable expansion](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#inline-python-variable-expansion). On older OE you might need to specify second parameter to `d.getVar`, like `d.getVar('BB_NO_NETWORK', True)`.

Comment: I tried both methods you suggested.  And they give different errors.  I've posted what I have got working so far and what I have tried which fails.

Comment: Ahh, it does work.  You need the alternate method you provided.  I had a mistake though.  I was using TRUE instead of True.  It works like a champ. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use base_conditional from `utils.bbclass`:

```
SRCREV = "${@base_conditional('BB_NO_NETWORK', '1', 'a2d1f0225692c7c054014ec4dfc4dd13a35245ee', '${AUTOREV}', d)}"
```

Comment: `base_conditional` was replaced by `oe.utils.conditional`, but the syntax is the same.